# Cómo sumar días a una fecha sin contar sábados y domingos?

Tags: typescript, funciones, date

por favor si pueden ayudar, tengo 2 variables
 **fecha y día** necesito con la fecha sumar los días para hacer un cálculo de fecha final pero que no tome en cuenta sábados y domingo con **typescript**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar algunos ejemplos?

Comment: El código va como texto. Ve a [edit]